# PHP Order in alphabetical order

Tags: php, list

I'm trying to make a simple alphabetical list to order items in my database. The thing I can't figure out is how to actually list it.

I would like it to be the same format as you have on miniclip.com

Here's an image

[image]

I looked around, but couldnt find an answer really.

(I would like it to finish even at the end of each vertical column, except the last one for sure)

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: Is javascript/jQuery an option for adjusting the layout?

Comment: If you're asking about the CSS and HTML part, and not PHP/MySqL, please make that more clear in the title and tags. Also, posting the HTML you have so far would help.

Answer (score 5):

In MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name ASC
```

In PHP:

```
$fruits = array("lemon", "orange", "banana", "apple");
sort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "fruits[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n";
}
fruits[0] = apple
fruits[1] = banana
fruits[2] = lemon
fruits[3] = orange
```

Comment: Alphabetical isn't asciibetical so it's necessary to lowercase all the entries before sorting. Or, if what is desired is a natural sort and not an ascii sort, `sort()` should be replaced with `natsort` or `natcasesort()`.

Answer (score 2):

He doesn't seem to have an issue with the storting, but doing the column format and headers for each new letter.

Suppose $arr contains your alphabetically sorted list with numeric keys.  each element has indexes 'name' and 'link'.  This should be pretty safe assumption for data from a SQL query.

```
$firstLetter = -1;
$desiredColumns = 4;  //you can change this!
$columnCount = (count($arr)+27)/$desiredColumns+1;
echo "<table><tr><td>";
foreach($arr as $key => $cur)
{
    if ($key != 0 && $key % desiredColumns == 0) echo "</td><td>";
    if ($cur['name'][0] !== $firstLetter)
    {
        echo "<strong>$firstLetter</strong> <br />"; $firstLetter = $cur['name'][0];
    }
    echo "<a href=".$cur['link'].">".$cur['name']."</a><br />";
}
echo "</td><tr></table>";
```

You'll have to treat numbers as a special case, but this is the idea.  If you are using a template engine there are obviously better ways of doing this, but I figure you would have mentioned that.  This is a rough sketch, making pretty HTML isn't my thing.

```
--Query-- get table into $arr.  I can't see your tables obviously, Im making assumptions if names nad stuff so you'll need to verify or change them

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table T ORDER BY name";
$conn = //you should have this
$res = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assc($res)
   $arr[] = $row;
// start above code here.  This isn't safe for empty query responses or other error but it works
```

Comment: This is what I was just trying to write up in between co-worker distractions. No one fully read the question and just assumed the user asked how to sort. Thank you for reading and replying. +1

Comment: note that i forgot to consider up to 26 letters (and one #) being listed separately from the names.  I made an edit on third line

Comment: Would you have an example with the actual query? I tried my best to fit it in, but failed (blank page), here I pasted one of my attempt, http://pastie.org/private/hosfojynwmbkgw2zv9bzeq. dont bother with the url for now, 'title' is actually the game title

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your result set already is sorted by using the `ORDER BY` clause, to group the results by their first character you just need to remember the first character of the previous entry and print out the first character of the current entry if they are different. So:

```
$prevLabel = null;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $currLabel = strtoupper(substr($row['name'], 0, 1));
    if ($currLabel !== $prevLabel) {
        echo $currLabel;
        $prevLabel = $currLabel;
    }
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

This will print the first character as a label for each group that’s members have the same first character.

Comment: @Alex Cane: Note that currently the characters actually need to be equal. So especially each number and any other character is treated as its own group. If you want to change that, you can use `strpbrk` or similar functions to lookup if the current label is actually an element of a special group like numbers (e.g. `if (strpbrk($currLabel, '0123456789') !== false) $currLabel = '#';`).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it.

You could use your database and use the 'order' clause to pull them by a specific field alphabetically.

You could also use either a key sort or value sort on a PHP array.

The PHP functions are sort($array) and ksort($array).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

```
<?php
  $list = $your_list_array_from_database
  //if you need info on how to do this, just let me know
  sort($list);

  foreach($list as $item) {
    echo $item;
  }
?>
```

Comment: I like everyone's giving answers about how to sort, even though the question is "how to actually list it", not "how to actually sort it".

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're using MySQL (or another SQL) database, in which case you should simply retrieve the data in the required order using a SORT BY clause on the lookup SELECT. (Sorting this PHP is trivial via the [sort](http://www.php.net/sort) function, but it makes sense to get the database to do this - that's pretty much what it's for.)

In terms of balancing the output of each of the columns, you could get a COUNT of the required rows in your database (or simply use the count of the resulting PHP array of data) and use this to ensure that the output is balanced.

As a final thought, if this is going to be output on a per-page basis, I'd highly recommend generating it into a static file when the structure changes and simply including this static file as a part of the output - generating this on the fly is needlessly resource inefficient.

Comment: Yea the problem isnt to list it, I didnt said it right. Im alright with the PHP side, its more the way of listing it, so when it reaches lets say 400px height, it makes a new column

Comment: @Alex so, your problem is actually with the CSS and html?

Answer (score 1):

The mysql option mentioned above is definitely the best bet.  If the data comes out of the DM in order, that's the simplest way to go.

Your next option might be to look at the 
asort and ksort functions in PHP to find the exact one you're looking for.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

How are you pulling the data?

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT titles FROM gamelist ORDER BY title ASC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "{$result['title']}<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Yeah that code is basically what I have, but breaking the line just makes new lines everytime doesnt it? Or will it create a new column if it reaches my div's height? That is where my problem is at, making a new column. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

I found this post and had the same problem.  I used the code below to output a list by category name with a header equal to the first letter.  In my database table (category) I have name and category_letter. So, name = football and category_list = 'F'.

```
<section>
    <?php
    try {
        $cats_sql = $dbo->prepare("SELECT name, category_list, FROM category WHERE category_list REGEXP '^[A-Z#]' GROUP BY category_list ASC");
        $cats_sql->execute();
        $results_cats = $cats_sql->fetchAll();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {  
        include('basehttp/error');
    }   
    $array_cats = $results_cats;
    if(is_array($array_cats)) {
        foreach($array_cats as $row_cats) {
            $cat_var = $row_cats[category_list]; // Each Category list title
            ?>
            <aside>
            <h1><a name=""><? echo $cat_var ?></a></h1> 
            <?php
            try {
                $search_sql = $dbo->prepare("SELECT name, category_list FROM category WHERE category_list=:cat_var ORDER BY name ASC"); // Pulling a list of names for the category list
                $search_sql->bindParam(":cat_var",$cat_var,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $search_sql->execute();
                $results_search = $search_sql->fetchAll();
            } catch(PDOException $e) {  
                include('basehttp/error');
            }   
            $array_search = $results_search;
            if(is_array($array_search)) { // Output list of names which match category
                foreach($array_search as $row_search) {
                    ?>
                    <h2><?php echo $row_search[name]; ?></h2>
                    <br class="clear">
                    <?php 
                }
            }
            ?>
            </aside>
            <br class="clear">
            <?php

        }
    }           
    ?>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its actually Simple....I did similar thing for my project once. I had to pull out all music albums name and categorize them in alphabetical order.

In my table, "album_name" is the column where names are stored.

```
$sql= "select * from album_table order by album_name ASC";
$temp_char= ""; // temporary variable, initially blank;
```

using while loop, iterate through records;

```
while($row= $rs->fetch_assoc())
{
$album_name= $row['album_name'];

$first_char_of_albm= $album_name[0]; // this will store first alphabet;

$first_char_of_albm= strtoupper($first_char_of_albm); // make uppercase or lower as per your needs 

if($temp_char!=$first_char_of_albm)
{
    echo $first_char_of_albm;

    $temp_char= $first_char_of_albm; // update $temp_char variable
}

}
```

That's it....

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my answer to this old question for 3 reasons:

1. You don't always get to write your queries to MySQL or another DBMS, as with a web service / API. None of the other answers address PHP sorting without query manipulation, while also addressing the vertical alphabetical sort
2. Sometimes you have to deal with associative arrays, and only a couple other answers deal with assoc. arrays. BTW, my answer will work for both associative and indexed arrays.
3. I didn't want an overly complex solution.

Actually, the solution I came up with was pretty simple--use multiple  tags with style="float:left", inside of a giant table. While I was sceptical that having multiple tbody tags in a single table would pass HTML validation, it in fact did pass without errors.

Some things to note:

- **$numCols** is your desired number of columns.
- Since we are floating items, you may need to set the width and min-width of parent elements and/or add some <br style="clear: both" />, based on your situation.
- for alternative sorting methods, see http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Here's my full answer:

```
function sortVertically( $data = array() )
{
    /* PREPARE data for printing */
    ksort( $data );     // Sort array by key.
    $numCols    = 4;    // Desired number of columns
    $numCells   = is_array($data) ? count($data) : 1 ;
    $numRows    = ceil($numCells / $numCols);
    $extraCells = $numCells % $numCols;  // Store num of tbody's with extra cell
    $i          = 0;    // iterator
    $cCell      = 0;    // num of Cells printed
    $output     = NULL; // initialize 


    /* START table printing */
    $output     .= '<div>';
    $output     .= '<table>';

    foreach( $data as $key => $value )
    {
        if( $i % $numRows === 0 )   // Start a new tbody
        {
            if( $i !== 0 )          // Close prev tbody
            {
                $extraCells--;
                if ($extraCells === 0 )
                {
                    $numRows--;     // No more tbody's with an extra cell
                    $extraCells--;  // Avoid re-reducing numRows
                }
                $output .= '</tbody>';
            }

            $output .= '<tbody style="float: left;">';
            $i = 0;                 // Reset iterator to 0
        }
        $output .= '<tr>';
            $output .= '<th>'.$key.'</th>';
            $output .= '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
        $output .= '</tr>';

        $cCell++;                   // increase cells printed count
        if($cCell == $numCells){    // last cell, close tbody
            $output .= '</tbody>';
        }

        $i++;
    }

    $output .= '</table>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    return $output;
}
```

I hope that this code will be useful to you all.